# Get the convex hull formed by griddata

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to get the function f(x,y) formed by grid data which represents the convex hull. Actually, I want to get the points(simplex points) that griddata uses to interpolate a particular point. I mean instead of griddata just giving me the end results, is it possible to get the intermediate values.

I have found that it uses delaunay triangulation to form the convex hull. It could be given by delaunay function of matlab. How can I get the simplexes where my interpolation points belong then?

Is it possible to get source code of griddata function in matlab so that I can make the changes?

Comment: I have used griddata.I am actually trying to tweak griddata. That's why I am asking if I could get its source or something

Comment: I didn't ask, "Did you try `griddata`?"  I asked, "Did you try `edit griddata`?"  The `edit` command will show you the source code of any MatLab function implemented in an M-file, which is most of them.